# Setting group order on pySankey sankey chart

Tags: python, charts, sankey-diagram

I'm trying to use a sankey chart to show some user segmentation change using PySankey but the class order is the opposite to what I want. Is there a way for me to specify the order in which each class is posted?
Here is the code I'm using (a dummy version):

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'curr_seg':np.repeat(['A','B','C','D'],4),
    'new_seg':['A','B','C','D']*4,
    'num_users':np.random.randint(low=10, high=20, size=16)
})

sankey(
    left=test_df["curr_seg"], right=test_df["new_seg"], 
    leftWeight= test_df["num_users"], rightWeight=test_df["num_users"], 
    aspect=20, fontsize=20
)
```

Which produces this chart:

[image: Sankey Chart]

I want to have the A class first and the D class latest on both left and right axis. Does anybody know how can I set it up? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in the first line of `check_data_matches_labels` function, you need to change to the following:
`if len(labels) > 0:`
Then you can use `leftLabels` and `rightLabels` to control order.

Answer (score 0):

The bug that IIIIR is talking about is fixed in [pySankeyBeta](https://pypi.org/project/pySankeyBeta/), install it with `pip install pySankeyBeta` instead.